# Why isn't my perspective transform working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, 3d

I am building a test 3D renderer in WinForms using the objects in `System.Numerics` such as `Vector3` and `Matrix4x4`.

The object drawn is a point cloud, centered around `(0,0,0)`, and rotated about the origin. Each node renders as dots on the screen. Here is what the 3D shape should look like

**Fake Perspective**

[image: fig1]

and more specifically when viewed from the front the perspective should be obvious with the blue dots that are further away from the eye to be at a smaller distance from the center

**Fake Perspective**

[image: fig2]

The pipeline is roughly as follows:

1. Rotation transformation

   ```
   Matrix4x4 RY = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(ry);
   ```
2. Perspective transformation (`fov=90`, `aspect=1.0f`, `near=1f`, `far=100f`)

   ```
   Matrix4x4 P = Matrix4x4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(fov.Radians(), 1.0f, 1f, 100f);
   ```
3. Camera transformation

   ```
   Matrix4x4 C = RY * P;
   var node = Vector3.Transform(face.Nodes[i], C);
   ```
4. Project to 2D

   ```
   Vector2 point = new Vector2(node.X, node.Y);
   ```
5. View transformation

   ```
   Matrix3x2 S = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(height / scale, -height / scale);
   Matrix3x2 T = Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(width / 2f, height / 2f);
   Matrix3x2 V = S*T
   point = Vector2.Transform(point, V);
   ```
6. Pixel Coordinates & Render

   ```
   PointF pixel = new PointF(point.X, point.Y);       
   e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush,pixel.X - 2, pixel.Y - 2, 4, 4);
   ```

So what I am seeing is an orthographic projection.

**Program Output**

[image: fig3]

[image: fig4]

The blue nodes further away are not smaller as expected. Somehow the perspective transformation is being ignored.

**So my question is my usage of `Matrix4x4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView()` correct in step #2? And is the projection from 3D to 2D in step #4 correct?**

Steps #1, #5 and #6 seem to be working exactly as intended, my issue is with steps #2-#4 somewhere.

---

### Example code to reproduce the issue

#### Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Shape Object { get; set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.Object = Shape.DemoShape1();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        float width = ClientSize.Width, height = ClientSize.Height;
        float scale = 40f, fov = 90f;

        Matrix4x4 RY = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(ry);
        Matrix4x4 RX = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX(rx);
        Matrix4x4 P = Matrix4x4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(fov.Radians(), 1.0f, 1f, 100f);

        Matrix4x4 C = RY * RX * P;

        Matrix3x2 S = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(
            height / scale, -height / scale);
        Matrix3x2 T = Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(
            width / 2f, height / 2f);

        Matrix3x2 V = S * T;
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 0))
        {
            var arrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(4f, 9.0f);
            pen.CustomEndCap = arrow;

            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
            {
                // Draw coordinate triad (omited)

                // Each face has multiple nodes with the same color
                foreach (var face in Object.Faces)
                {
                    brush.Color = face.Color;
                    PointF[] points = new PointF[face.Nodes.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // transform nodes into draw points
                        var item = Vector4.Transform(face.Nodes[i], C);
                        var point = Vector2.Transform(item.Project(), V);
                        points[i] = point.ToPoint();
                    }
                    // Draw points as dots
                    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush,
                            points[i].X - 2, points[i].Y - 2,
                            4, 4);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### GraphicsExtensions.cs

```
public static class GraphicsExtensions
{
    public static PointF ToPoint(this Vector2 vector)
        => new PointF(vector.X, vector.Y);
    public static Vector2 Project(this Vector3 vector)
        => new Vector2(vector.X, vector.Y);
    public static Vector2 Project(this Vector4 vector)
        => new Vector2(vector.X, vector.Y);

    public static float Radians(this float degrees) => (float)(Math.PI/180) * degrees;
    public static float Degrees(this float radians) => (float)(180/Math.PI) * radians;
}
```

[image: fig5]